# how to create alias name for scriptmethod in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

We can create alias name for function.

Is there a way to create alias name for Scriptmethod (created by Add-member)?

The scenario is as below.

```
$TestSuite | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod TestId_6099 {

}
```

We are having test suite where a method name TestId_6099 is there.
This method is doing for example: Check Disk limit exceed event.

So the proper name could be

```
$TestSuite | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod CheckDiskLimitExceedAlert {

}
```

Then there should be alias name for the scriptmethod should be as TestId_6099.

There is an aliasproperty membertype but it is not working for scriptmethod. How to create alias name for ScriptMethod?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hacky, but you *can* have a self-referencing `ScriptMethod`:

```
$TestProject = New-Object PsObject

$TestProject | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod TestId_6099 {
    Write-Host "Hell Is For Heroes"
}

$TestProject | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod GreatestBandEver {
    $this.TestId_6099()
}

$TestProject.GreatestBandEver()
```

**Result:** `Hell Is For Heroes`